# Limit on EMR Cluster history?

Tags: node.js, amazon-emr

I'm trying to programatically render the count of EMR clusters using NodeJS for reporting purpose

Even though there are 100+ EMR clusters in our environment, the below code is only finding 50 records. Is there a limitation and how do I get the full count?

```
var params = {
  ClusterStates: [
    "STARTING",
    "BOOTSTRAPPING",
    "RUNNING",
    "WAITING",
    "TERMINATING",
    "TERMINATED",
    "TERMINATED_WITH_ERRORS"
  ]
};

emr.listClusters(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
  else     console.log(data.Clusters.length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a default limit from AWS. Closing the question